# How to make mysql generated posts to be independent onn their own

Tags: php, mysql, sql, comments

i am retrieving posts from a table called post . I wanted to add a commenting feature to this code, The problem is that the latest posts variables are dominant over others in that if you comment on an older post, the variables of the "**latest post(which appears first because of the ORDER BY ID DECS criteria"** 
 Someone help me make this posts independent on their own...Thanks

```
 <?php

    $sqlhash="SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC ";
        $result_hash = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlhash);
        while($rowhash = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result_hash))
        {
            $user = $rowhash['user'];
            $message = $rowhash['post'];
            $time =  $rowhash['time'];
        $id=  $rowhash['id'];
            $tt = date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$time);

    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];




     $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Full_name='$user'  ";
      $result_set = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result_set))
      {

        $select_username = $row['Full_name'];
        $profp = $row['pic'];



    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];


    ?>

<center><div class='post' style='width:48%; height:40%; align:middle; text-align:left; margin:30px 0'>
<img width="70" height="70" src='uploads/<?php echo $profp; ?>'><br><p style='color:#0c88b5'><b>  <?php echo $id ;?><br><?php echo $user ;?>On:<?php echo $tt ; ?><h4><b><?php echo $message 
;?></h4></p><hr>
<?php 

$sqlcom="SELECT * FROM comment WHERE hash='$id' ";
    $result_com = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlcom);
    while($rowcom = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result_com))
    {
        $usercom = $rowcom['comment'];
        $comenter = $rowcom['user'];

echo "<p style='color:#0c88b5' $comenter</p>". ":" ;
 echo $usercom. "<br>" ;

 }
if (isset($_POST['commen'])) {


$sqlhash= "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post= '$message' ";
    $result_hash = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlhash);
    while($rowhash = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result_hash))
    {
        $user1 = $_SESSION['username'];
        $comment = $_POST['commen'];
        $time =  $rowhash['time'];



        $time2 = $_SESSION['time'];



 $sql3 = "INSERT INTO comment (user, comment, hash) VALUES
             ('$user1','$comment', '$id')";

             if($conn->query($sql3) === TRUE) {

header('Location: timeline.php');

}else {
    echo"error";
}
```

Comment: Are you maintaining thread like structure for post and its reply?

Comment: no mayank. i am simply saving them to a database and then retrieving them as they come... i then wanted to add a commenting feature but i am unable to comment on any specific post because of the last post overiding the others.. help me with all the technologies to make this system better

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes at database level in your post table to manage the reply thread on a post.

1. Add a parent_id column with default null that contains the post id for which the reply or comment is made.
2. For each comment or reply, put an entry in parent_id column.
3. To show post, fetch the records having parent_id **IS NULL**. By this you will get the post only, put order by on id to get in a proper order.
4. For each post you can retrieve comment or reply by putting a condition like parent_id **IS NOT NULL**

This will help you.

Comment: hey mayank i have done that and if i try to save a reply with the parent_id of the comment it picks the parent_id of the last post that was entered..